# Get Venue Information From Existing Event

Tags: social-tables

I'm trying to get the venue information for existing events (specifically, the name and address) - i.e. this stuff:

[image]

Is there a way to pull this (if it exists)? I've been looking at the legacy spaces API, but it seems like the address is always blank and I can't find anywhere in the UI to fill it in (may just be a gap in my knowledge):

```
{
    "data": [
        {
  "id": 8604969,
  "event_id": 4466623,
  "space_template_id": null,
  "space_order": 0,
  "active": 1,
  "name": "Salon A",
  "added_dimension": null,
  "service_area_perimeter": null,
  "width": null,
  "length": null,
  "address": null,
  "state": null,
  "city": null,
  "zip": null,
  "floorplan_image": null,
  "floor_background": null,
  "height": null,
  "custom_bg_color": null,
  "creator_id": null,
  "chair_type": "chiavari",
  "occupancy": null,
  "archived": 0,
  "wall_texture": null,
  "wall_texture_imported": null,
  "max_occupancy": null,
  "usable_space": null,
  "attendee_count": 0,
  "exiting_required": 0,
  "sq_ft_per_extinguisher": null,
  "override_attendee_count": 0,
  "linen_texture": null,
  "deleted": 0,
  "img_url": null,
  "thumb_img_url": null,
  "img_last_updated": null,
  "bookable_room_id": 462580,
  "rotation": 0,
  "updated_at": "2019-09-01T15:08:02.000Z",
  "team_id": 225389,
  "notes": null,
  "total_exiting": 0,
  "venue_id": "S462580",
  "bookable_room": "S462580",
  "imageSizes": {
    "original": "https://socialtables-space-images-resized.s3.amazonaws.com/8604969-original.png",
    "grid": "https://socialtables-space-images-resized.s3.amazonaws.com/8604969-grid.png",
    "onsiteSmall": "https://socialtables-space-images-resized.s3.amazonaws.com/8604969-onsite-small.png",
    "onsiteLarge": "https://socialtables-space-images-resized.s3.amazonaws.com/8604969-onsite-large.png"
  }
}
]
}
```

### Update

I've figured out how to wind my way to this point that appears to give the "raw" address - is there a way to get it formatted or separated by street/city/state/etc.? Does social tables support international addresses?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't expose that information through the API at this point.  We are looking at improving the property information.